# How to set different ids for each control in each gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with columns manually defined. I have several rows (I use a button to add a row). My problem is that all controls in the same column have the same id, and thus I can't use JQuery Datepicker for my Date column (called Fecha).

I believe I can get the add a row button to work (keeping old data) with control ids like txtFecha1, txtFecha2, etc. But where should I set those names?

I should mention I would also settle for a way to make JQuery datepicker work on controls with the same id, but many answers state that it won't work, since datepicker is asuming that I'm a good programmer and I set a different id for every control.

Code for the GridView:

```
        <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
        ID="gvActividades" runat="server" EmptyDataText="Error" AllowPaging="False"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvActividades_OnRowDataBound"
        OnRowDeleting="gvActividades_RowDeleting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Técnico">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="cboTecnico">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Fecha">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control datepicker" ID="txtFecha" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Hora de inicio">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="txtHoraInicio" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Hora de fin">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="txtHoraFin" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Repuesto">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="cboRepuesto">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Cantidad">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="txtCantidad" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Descripción">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="txtDescripcion" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gvSelectedRowStyle" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="gvPagerStyle" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code for the add a row button (the method called when pressing the button):

```
    protected void cmdAgregarFila_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null == ViewState["CurrentTable"])
    {
        return;
    }
    int rowIndex = 0;

    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList cboTecnico =
             (DropDownList)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("cboTecnico");
            TextBox txtFecha =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtFecha");
            TextBox txtHoraInicio =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtHoraInicio");
            TextBox txtHoraFin =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtHoraFin");
            DropDownList cboRepuesto =
          (DropDownList)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("cboRepuesto");
            TextBox txtCantidad =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtCantidad");
            TextBox txtDescripcion =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtDescripcion");
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col1"] = cboTecnico.SelectedValue;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col2"] = txtFecha.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col3"] = txtHoraInicio.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col4"] = txtHoraFin.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col5"] = cboRepuesto.SelectedValue;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col6"] = txtCantidad.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col7"] = txtDescripcion.Text;
            rowIndex++;
        }
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

        gvActividades.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        gvActividades.DataBind();
    }

    SetPreviousData();
}
```

Other methods for the row-adding to work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FirstGridViewRow();
    }
}

private void FirstGridViewRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col4", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col5", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col6", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col7", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Col1"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Col2"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Col3"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Col4"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Col5"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Col6"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Col7"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    gvActividades.DataSource = dt;
    gvActividades.DataBind();
}

private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList cboTecnico =
              (DropDownList)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("cboTecnico");
                TextBox txtFecha =
                  (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtFecha");
                TextBox txtHoraInicio =
                  (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtHoraInicio");
                TextBox txtHoraFin =
                  (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtHoraFin");
                DropDownList cboRepuesto =
              (DropDownList)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("cboRepuesto");
                TextBox txtCantidad =
                  (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtCantidad");
                TextBox txtDescripcion =
                  (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtDescripcion");

                cboTecnico.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString();
                txtFecha.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString();
                txtHoraInicio.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col3"].ToString();
                txtHoraFin.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col4"].ToString();
                cboRepuesto.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Col5"].ToString();
                txtCantidad.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col6"].ToString();
                txtDescripcion.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col7"].ToString();
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void gvActividades_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    SetRowData();
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowIndex]);
            drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            gvActividades.DataSource = dt;
            gvActividades.DataBind();

            SetPreviousData();
            //actualizarTotal();
        }
    }
}

private void SetRowData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (null == ViewState["CurrentTable"])
    {
        return;
    }
    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList cboTecnico =
              (DropDownList)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("cboTecnico");
            TextBox txtFecha =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtFecha");
            TextBox txtHoraInicio =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtHoraInicio");
            TextBox txtHoraFin =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtHoraFin");
            DropDownList cboRepuesto =
          (DropDownList)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("cboRepuesto");
            TextBox txtCantidad =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtCantidad");
            TextBox txtDescripcion =
              (TextBox)gvActividades.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtDescripcion");

            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col1"] = cboTecnico.SelectedValue;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col2"] = txtFecha.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col3"] = txtHoraInicio.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col4"] = txtHoraFin.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col5"] = cboRepuesto.SelectedValue;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col6"] = txtCantidad.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col7"] = txtDescripcion.Text;
            rowIndex++;
        }

        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
    }

    SetPreviousData();
}
```

Comment: why not simply add an attribute or assign a class to your html elements?

Comment: Use `ClientIDMode = "Predictable"` _instead of_ `Static`

Comment: They have a class datepicker, set like this: `class="form-control datepicker"`. My problem, consistent with many questions here in SO, is that while the JQuery datepicker opens for any txtFecha, it always modifies the control on the first row, since it's the first it encounters with that id, no matter from which row the function is called.

Comment: @mshsayem damn, so simple, works perfectly!! Thanks a lot! Please put it as an answer so other people find it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` instead of `ClientIDMode="Static"` inside the item-templates.